# Reword last commit message on master/main branch after pushing?

Tags: git, gitlab

I managed to push some changes with a poor commit message to my master branch.
Here is my sequence of git commands:

```
git branch -b myperfectfeature
(i wrote excellent code)
git add .
git commit -m "Add awesom stuff"
git checkout main
git merge --ff-only myperfectfeature
git push origin main
```

Then I realised I spelled something wrong in the commit message.
I tried to reword the commit message by using:

```
git commit --amend
```

But when I now try to push with:

```
git push origin main -f
```

I get the following error:

> ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to '.../myrepo.git'

I guess my GitLab repository does not allow non-fast-forward pushes (?).

Is there any way I can reword my last commit message on my main branch and preserve my changes?

Comment: The branch is probably protected and you can't directly push to it.

Comment: Don't you get a message from gitlab that the branch is protected?

Comment: Yes, it appears the branch is flagged as "Protected". If there's no way to revert my changes, I'll just have to live with it I guess and be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the settings to allow non-fast-forward force pushes, if you have the permissions to do so. You could also delete the branch and re-push it.

Though it is technically possible to solve, I'd recommend you consider if it is worth it. If someone else has pulled the branch already and you rewrite the commits they are likely to end up with problems. Since you already pushed it, I'd prefer to not mess with the history.